# Script entered data into the database - should colons be given special treatment

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

So I wrote a script that basically reads data from a txt file and populates this model.

```
class modelNursing(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")
```

This is the simple script (it looks like this). Essentially the txt file contain a string on each line and this script extracts each line string and enters that string into the db as an entry.

```
def PopulateNursing(request):
    with open('../content.txt') as fp:
        try:
            for line in fp:
                try:
                    modelNursing.objects.create(item=line)
                except Exception as e:
                    print str(e)
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)
```

Now here is the funny part one of the items `modelNursing` instance in the database has the item value equal to "Vitals:q4". So doing something like this

```
nursing = modelNursing.objects.filter(item="Vitals:q4")
```

should return a row but unfortunately it does not.So I went into the admin interface to double check if the entry was really there and yes it was there.
I then noticed if I delete the column in the string `Vitals:q4` from the admin interface and then add it again and save then the query works.Any suggestions on why this might be happening ? Is there a chance that the automation script might be screwing up the colon insertion or something.Why do I have to delete the column in each entry and reinsert it and then save it. Any advice would be appreciated. I am baffled.

**Update:**

Actually I noticed that if I simply went into the admin section and into the entry instance and simply saved again the query works.Again why do I have to goto the entry instance and save again for the query to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `line` contains `\n` end of the line. So your filter isn't macthing `"Vitals:q4"` because there is no record with this `item`.

```
nursing = modelNursing.objects.filter(item="Vitals:q4\n")
```

So you should do

```
modelNursing.objects.create(item=line.strip())
```

Comment: Ahhh that totally makes sense. I am going to try this and get back

Comment: yep that was the problem